# Java POI - can't access xls file on Win 2003 Server

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i have a small app. it takes xls file and transforms it into xml. everything works fine on my two local machines win xp 32 (java 7) and win 7 64 (java 8) but when i started app on win 2003 server things went a bit strange.

on win server it gives me error:

```
org.apache.poi.EmptyFileException: The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long)
at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:218)

at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:168)

at Parser.xlsToXml(Parser.java:43)
at Parser.<init>(Parser.java:28)
```

as you can see i use java poi lib to parse xls.

this is part of code where error occures:

```
Biff8EncryptionKey.setCurrentUserPassword(params.get("pass"));
NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(new File(params.get("xls_location")), true);//string 43!!!
```

before i try to access this xls file i'm successfully getting params for app to work from text file located in the same folder on server as xls file is with this code:

```
encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(dir+fileName));
return new String(encoded,getFileCharset(dir+fileName));
```

so i mean that i have all rights for reading and writing in the directory.

i tried to google this but found nothing that could help. i'm really stuck here. folder on the server has same right as folders on my win xp and win 7 home computers. also i allways use the same xls file on all machines.

so what do i do wrong?..

any help appriciated!

Comment: Error is pretty clear: "The supplied file was empty (zero bytes long)"

Comment: file is not empty. its almost about 10mb

Comment: Sure `params.get("xls_location")` is the path to the right file? What `String` is returned by  `params.get("xls_location")`?

Comment: yes. i tried "/file.xls","\\file.xls","./file.xls","D:/shared/file.xls","D:\\shared\\file.xls","D:\shared\file.xls".

Comment: You mention that `Paths.get(dir+fileName)` is in the same folder. So why not `NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(Paths.get(dir+"/file.xls").toFile(), true)` or `NPOIFSFileSystem fs = new NPOIFSFileSystem(Paths.get(dir+"file.xls").toFile(), true)` if `dir` ends with `/` already.

Comment: wow, i did as you said and it worked!!!!! thak you a lot!